# Получить числа из строки

Tags: java

Есть строка, она содержит числа, допустим, пароль - 450. Как получить это число? Строка может содержать русский текст.

Comment: То есть в строке не только одно число, а что-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если знаете структуру строки, можете использовать [регулярные выражения](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/regexp.html).

Comment: `/(\d+)/` 

=)

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?");
Matcher matcher=pat.matcher("45.5saf -fg123 -18+");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
};
```

Так можно получить все числа из строки.
Результат этого примера 45.5; 123; -18.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да, ваш код лучше.

Comment: Регулярное выражение не верное) например `44..1`

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой код найдет все числа в строке:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    String word = "test123test444test"; // мой пример строки
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    int start = 0;
    while (matcher.find(start)) {
       String value = word.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
       int result = Integer.parseInt(value);
       System.out.println(result);
       start = matcher.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s1 ="пароль - 450";
String s2 = s1.split("\\\D+");
//s2 - символьный массив всех числовых вхождений.
```

Вопрос старый, но поисковики выводят ее практически первой. Мало ли кому пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1 = "тестовое сообщение 34567";
String[] s2_array = s1.split("\\D+");
Integer numbers = Integer.parseInt(String.join("", s2_array));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: этот код неверный, читайте вопрос